# Json to Dataframe Conversion using Python

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I want to convert the below json to dataframe which looks like in the picture attached.
I have tried below code but gives an error " string indices must be integers".
Please help.

```
def on_input(data):
#    df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data["data"])
    api.send("output", df)

api.set_port_callback("input1", on_input)
```

[JSON FORMAT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rhhCU.png)

[Expected DF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVSvz.png)

Comment: amend your question to include sample input and expected output as text

Comment: it looks as simple as `pd.json_normalize(data["data"])`